# How do you animate character's interaction with different objects?

Tags: animation

If a character interacts only with one object that's easy: just add one **Child Of** constraint and you are good to go.But throughout the animation a character might pick up and release thousands of objects. It means having a **Child Of** constraint for every single object that the character interacts with. That way the character can end up with having thousands of constraints on it. My question is: how do you animate a complex scene where a character must interact with different objects?

Comment: could you please give an example because I guess each situation is different and needs its own trick

Comment: It it is not project specific question. In general how people deal with a character having multiple objects to interact with.

Comment: as you said Child Of seems to be the simplest solution, in what case a character would have hundreds of objects to interact with (meaning hold and drop)? Again, I don't think you can say that it's not a project specific question, because each situation might need a different approach and solution